# Include cookie from response headers in request headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.1, traefik

I am running multiple instances of .NET Core application behind Traefik reverse proxy. When user visits website, Traefik sends back StickyCookie (inside Set-Cookie):

[image]

It tells the client which server behind Traefik accepted his request. If we want to send request to the same server again, we have to include the cookie in request as well.

How can I implement middleware in .NET Core which will append StickyCookie field to every request? It should include same StickyCookie as it received from previous response.

Basically, I want to achieve same as following Linux command:

`curl -v --cookie "StickyCookie=http://10.0.2.75:80" http://example.com:5000`

Answer (score 0):

A middleware can be registred to send anything in the response header. You can register the middleware in the startup.cs file Configure method:

```
  app.UseMiddleware<CustomHeader>();
```

And your CustomHeader class can then be

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PEG.Api.Middleware
{
    public class CustomHeader
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CustomHeader(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //you can add your stickyCookie in the dictionary
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
            {
                /* add your sticky cookie here. An example below
                 {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",new string[]{"true" }
                }*/
            };

            //To add Headers AFTER everything you need to do this
            context.Response.OnStarting(state => {
                var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
                foreach (var item in dictionary)
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }, context);

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this. But I don't know how I can append `StickyCookie` (that we previously received from response) to every client's **request**? So the workflow is something like this: 1. client opens website, 2. StickyCookie is sent in response header, 3. this same StickyCookie must be present in every request header from then on.

Comment: Do you have a web API driven .net core application on the server and an independent client application ?

Comment: No, I use .NET Core MVC on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `StickyCookie` in response header in middleware and then save it into [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-session-state), then you could retrieve the data from session and add it to request header.

```
public class AddHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AddHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {

        var data = context.Session.GetString("StickyCookie");

        context.Request.Headers.Add("StickyCookie", data);

        context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
        {
            var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
            var cookies = httpContext.Response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].ToString().Split(";");
            if (cookies.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in cookies)
                {
                    if (item.Split("=")[0] == "StickyCookie")
                    {
                        var cookie = item.Split("=")[1];
                        httpContext.Session.SetString("StickyCookie", cookie);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }, context);

        await _next(context);
    }
}

public static class AddHeaderMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAddHeader(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AddHeaderMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            //// Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            //// Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
 }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     //...
     app.UseSession();
     app.UseAddHeader();
     //...
}
```

Action to check:

```
var header = HttpContext.Request.Headers;
```

Comment: @Mark Do you want to send request from asp.net core (in controller or middleware) with cookie header to your backend server(php server maybe)?